# Oracle Generic DB Link not working

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, odbc, dblink

I'm trying to use oracle's hsodbc generic database link driver to access a postgresql database from my oracle 10gr2 database server.  I think I have everything configured but I'm receiving this error from the sqlplus promt after trying a remote query.

```
SQL> select * from temp_user@intranet;
select * from temp_user@intranet
                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from INTRANET
```

If I use "isql" from the linux command line (in other words test just the odbc connection) the query works.

I enter in   "isql intranet"   (intranet is the name of the odbc connection)
I get the prompt I type   select * from temp_user and I receive back my 157 records on screen.

So I know the odbc configuration is setup correctly.  Here is what I do for oracle.

```
%oracle_home/hs/admin/inithsodbc.ora
HS_FDS_CONNECT_INFO = intranet
HS_FDS_TRACE_LEVEL = OFF
HS_FDS_SHAREABLE_NAME = /usr/bin/ODBCConfig
```

```
%oracle_home/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
INTRANET =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.5.1)(PORT = 5432))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = INTRANET)
    )
    (HS = OK)

%oracle_home/network/admin/listener.ora
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = INTRANET)
      (PROGRAM = hsodbc)
      (SID_NAME = INTRANET)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /home/oracle/app/OraHomeTEST)
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = oracledb.andersen-const.com)(PORT = 5432))
    )
  )
```

I have restarted the listener.  It's status is as follows.

```
Services Summary...
Service "INTRANET" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "INTRANET", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
```

I then go into sqlplus from the database server command line and do the following.

```
drop database link intranet;
```

create database link intranet connect to auser identified by apassword using 'intranet';

This is successful.

However when I run

```
 select * from temp_user@intranet
```

I receive the error

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28545: error diagnosed by Net8 when connecting to an agent
Unable to retrieve text of NETWORK/NCR message 65535
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from INTRANET
```

I've spend atleast a good day going back over the configures and trying things and I always get this error.

Anybody have any good ideas,

Comment: What's that `isql` tool?

Answer (score 1):

What does "tnsping intranet" report?

Are you sure your hsodbc prorgram is in the Oracle_home/bin directory of the your gateway installation? Also, is your LD_LIBRARY_PATH set properly?

I believe your LD_LIBRARY_PATH should be $ORACLE_HOME/lib. Sorry, not sure since I don't do much with *Nix these days.

Comment: Sorry forget to add that.  It reports the following.

TNS Ping Utility for Linux: Version 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on 25-JUN-2009 09:15:12

Copyright (c) 1997, 2006, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.5.1)(PORT = 5432))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = INTRANET)) (HS = OK))
OK (0 msec)

Comment: Ok looks like it might be my ld_library_path  here is the latest.  What should this path be.

[oracle@oracledb ~]$ hsodbc
[oracle@oracledb ~]$ which hsodbc
~/app/OraHomeTEST/bin/hsodbc
[oracle@oracledb ~]$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH


the echo command returns nothing.